# Mobile and Desktop Web Application with Server Push

Tags: web-applications, responsive-design, architecture, vaadin

I am looking to build a hybrid mobile and desktop web application capable of doing server push to the clients, but need some advice on preferable technologies and routes I should look into or take. What is a modern and easy way to handle the server push back to the client layer from the backend? I'd also like to add that I have not worked with many front-end technologies that might be helpful in this scenario, but would love to try some if they will get the job done.

Here is a rough diagram showing the scenario that I want to achieve. More details and desired flow bellow.

[image: Step 1]

1. Desktop-1 is the first one to log-in, sets up some settings and is in control of the next action.

2. As future clients log in, others are notified via server push and UI is updated reflecting this. Rest of the clients that have joined are now waiting for an action to be performed by Desktop-1.

3. Desktop-1 performs an action that is sent to the backend.

4. The backend sends a push message to all other clients with the updated data so they can refresh UIs reflecting the new current state.

5. Next to perform an action is one of the clients that has not yet had a turn and the process repeats.

*Resemble something like a turn-based game.*


• Accessed via mobile/desktop browser. 
• Only one client at a time is in control and is able to issue an action. 
• I do not expect a large number of clients (around 10), but learning any new technology that can scale will be interesting. 
• Simple UI--No real preference on look and feel or UI framework.

**What I have looked at so far that might make my task feasible:**

• Having done some GWT apps before, Vaadin looks like an interesting and suitable choice. Maybe serve a TouchKit UI for mobile and regular for desktop. 
• Spring Boot, Bootstrap, Java backend with WebSockets or some framework -- Errai/Atmosphere.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer this from the Vaadin perspective:

Vaadin is ideally suited for this, since it handles all your requirements out of the box.

With the correct UI theme and layout you can get a responsive UI for the different client types.

Server push is already existing, with multiple levels of fallback, depending the clients capabilities.

The only thing you will need to implement your self (or use a addon) is the "broadcasting" of the messages from Desktop1 to all others and vice versa.
For this, there exist some event bus style addons, which allows the different clients to communicate together.

Scaling is not a big problem for some hunderd users, unless you store too much information on the user sessions on the server.
But it could be a bandwith problem, when you must publish the message to 499 other clients, depending on the message size.
Test is no problem, but "broadcasting" videos to 499 clients tends to be slow.